# Adding binary to ~/.local/bin

Tags: administrator, binary

In short, I have a working executable in my home directory. I want to make the executable available in the Terminal for the current user in any directory.

More context: The executable is `geckodriver`. The book I am using, *Test-Driven Development with Python* by Harry J.W. Percival, says "For macOS or Linux users, one convenient place to put [Geckodriver] is `~/.local/bin`"

Based on this suggestion, I thought I should do something like `mv geckodriver ~/.local/bin`. Turns out `~/.local/bin` is an executable, not a directory on my machine. This is keeping me from simply creating a `bin` directory in `~/.local`.

I think there is something fundamental I do not understand here. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did was move the `geckodriver` executable into ~/.local, and rename it to `bin`. The directory must exist first before mv can move anything into it, or it will assume you intend to rename the file at the destination. You can either delete ~/.local/bin with `rm ~/.local/bin` and make the directory with `mkdir ~/.local/bin`, then redownload it, or you can run the command `mv ~/.local/bin ~/.local/geckodriver && mkdir ~/.local/bin && mv ~/.local/geckodriver ~/.local/bin`, so you don't have to redownload it.